# Extracting text within an image embedded in a pdf using itext in Android

Tags: itext

I am developing an android application in which I have to parse pdf files . Some pdf files contains images (image comtaining text) . I want to parse the text within the images . How to do this using iText library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iText, you can extract the image(s) in the pdf document. But iText does not do OCR (optical character recognition). So it's up to you to extract the text from the images afterwards.

Depending on the volume, and your specific use-case, I would encourage you to use the google cloud API. They offer solutions to handle recognizing text in image.

Or, as the google developer console says: "Integrates Google Vision features, including image labeling, face, logo, and landmark detection, optical character recognition (OCR), and detection of explicit content, into applications."

Checkout https://console.developers.google.com for more information.

Kind regards,
Joris